# 2 connections for improved speed?

Tags: networking, connection, internet-speed

I have a small office with 8 computers on the network. Our local internet is OK but we want to improve our speed. I have two internet lines into the office so how can I use these to improve speed? Do I have two separate routers and connect 4 computers to one and 4 to another? FYI one connection also has telephony (phone, fax and alarm)
many thanks
ian

Comment: What speed do you want to improve? Internet access? Is it VOIP telephony?

Comment: Thank you. I want to improve internet access as we are working in media and constantly visiting new sites. W